# Two .xcodeproj files in one project. Unable to determine which one to remove and how

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, xcode-project, xcodeproj

**Iam having two .xcodeproj files in one project, While running via VSCode, i am getting this error/message**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro in debug mode...

lib/main.dart:1
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
Command line invocation:
    /{some_Directory}/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -list

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

2022-06-24 16:15:22.906 xcodebuild[8086:79901] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-06-24 16:15:22.907 xcodebuild[8086:79901] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
xcodebuild: error: The directory /{path_to_project}/ios contains 2 projects, including multiple projects with the current extension (.xcodeproj). Specify the project to use with the -project option.
  Command: xcrun xcodebuild -list

Exited
```

### Project files

[image]

### When I remove one of them(runner.xcodeproj), this is the error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro in debug mode...

lib/main.dart:1

Expected ios/Runner.xcodeproj but this file is missing.
No application found for TargetPlatform.ios.
Is your project missing an ios/Runner/Info.plist?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.

Exited
```

### Again when I remove another one(ProjectNamed.xcodeproj), this error shows

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
The Xcode project defines schemes: {Project_Title}
Exception: You must specify a --flavor option to select one of the available schemes.
Exited
```